# Matching ID between two pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have, I guess a simple question but I cannot find the right answer. I have two pandas series (let's say "A" and "B") with ID in there (string). Series A is bigger than series B. What I am looking for is a way to have a resulting dataframe with 2 columns where the matching elements are on the same row and if there is a value in A that don't exist in B, to add a NaN.

```
A            B
10368        10368
12567        NaN
13456        13456
...          ...
```

and so on.

I guess the merge function in pandas can be helpful but I could not manage to make it work

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Demonstrate the effort by providing the code.

Comment: I tried many things. Merge, concat, intersection,.. but it resolves only part of the problem.

Comment: Fine. Where is the code demonstrating the effort?

Comment: Probably best to create a dictionary and use map canyou post a better sample of your input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin(df['B']), 'B'] = df['A']
df.loc[~df['A'].isin(df['B']), 'B'] = np.nan
```

Before:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  3  4
3  7  0
```

After:

```
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
3  7  NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I'll check now exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and boolean index using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
a = pd.Series(['10368', '12567', '13456'])
b = pd.Series(['10368', '13456'])

pd.concat([a, a[a.isin(b)]], axis=1)
```

[out]

```
       0      1
0  10368  10368
1  12567    NaN
2  13456  13456
```

Comment: Thanks too. It's pretty handy. I'll keep both solutions